# Clarification about logging

Tags: linux, logging

For some time, I've been confused about computer message logging.

1. As the article on Wikipedia said, Syslog is a standard for computer message logging. So are there any other standars beside syslog?
2. Is there any other way to log to remote server except syslog? (I've been using rsyslog and syslog-ng).
3. As the article on Wiki illustrated, Common Log Format is a standardized text file format used by web servers when generating server log files. So if those log files are in one common format, what does it mean to be supported log format of the server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Syslog is standard, systems based on systemd use [journald](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html) + [journalctl](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html).
2. You can use [logstash](https://github.com/elastic/logstash) .
3. Format means here that each message has a this structure:

   > host ident authuser date request status bytes
   >   Some app may have another structure of message, so it would be another log format. There is also binary log formats, like systemd has.